# No coding exp - Error please help :D

Tags: truffle-migration, error

I am trying to follow along with a tutorial on youtube. however i keep getting errors when i try to migrate.

This is the error - Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"MemoryToken" is an abstract contract or an interface and cannot be deployed.

- Import abstractions into the '.sol' file that uses them instead of deploying them separately.
- Contracts that inherit an abstraction must implement all its method signatures exactly.
- A contract that only implements part of an inherited abstraction is also considered abstract.

```
at Deployer._preFlightCheck (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:178:1)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
```

Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)

Comment: It is likely the MemoryToken contract requires some function to be implemented and you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. My problem is that I didn't delete the code "is ERC721Full" after "cotract MemoryToken". Because of the inherit of ERC721Full , it makes MemoryToken a abstract contract. if didn't implement the functions, it cant be deployed.